# Windows IE Regional Configuration and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, cultureinfo

I'm currently playing with an issue in the format of currency values across an ASP.NET application.
I've set up my webconfig to detect automatically the client culture and I manage as it's desired from the app. I have to show the values formatted depending on his regional config.

My question is if the Regional Configuration within control panel affects the IE language configuration (Tools>Options>Language).

Thanks

Comment: <<Regional Configuration within control panel affects the IE language configuration (Tools>Options>Language).>>  

Only before first run, as that's what helps set the default option under Tools/Options/Language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regional settings under contorl panel only affects the client PC. The lanuages IE send to server with each HTTP request are defined under Tools>Options>Language. Upon what received with each HHTP request, the server decided how to treat it.
You might get confusing results if you are using the same PC for server and client.